# Is it possible to Enable Focus Stealing under Wayland? (Gnome Shell 3.26, Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: nautilus, gedit, gnome-shell, wayland, focus

I've just switched over to Wayland from XOrg under Ubuntu 17.10.

Say I'm in Nautilus and I click on a text-file. It used to be for me that I was automatically switched over to gedit (every time I click on a file, even if gedit was already opened).

On Wayland, this happens on the first time I click on file (when gedit is opened the first time) but afterwards, it no longer switches. gedit simply  opens text files in the background without even a notification popup saying "blablabla.txt is ready in gedit".

Under XOrg gnome-shell, I used to be able to install a extension called [Steal My Focus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/234/steal-my-focus/) (there's also an updated version for 3.26 that could be found  [here](https://github.com/tak0kada/gnome-shell-extension-stealmyfocus)). Neither of these extensions seem to work anymore.

There was also a gsetting that did the same thing as these extensions:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows 'strict'
```

And that doesn't seem to work anymore either.

Since this is happening right after I switched over to Wayland, I'm guessing that this is Wayland related.

Anyone succeeded in disabling focus stealing protection under Wayland. If not, anyone have any ideas? suggestions?

Comment: Is gedit then opening new windows or new tabs?

Comment: Hi muru. This is only happening when gedit is opening new tabs.

Comment: Opened a bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/2192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not sure if this bug is only taking place in my machine or if it's more widespread. I could be wrong but I'm guessing this is probably due to some wayland security restriction that prevents apps from focusing already open windows (as far as I know the window manager is supposed to handle these things now and not the display server like in X). I'm assuming this is a transitional issue and that gnome will eventually give gedit the ability to focus new tabs.

While waiting for this fix, I came up with a partial fix that will send a notification when a new tab is opened in gedit. This doesn't fix the autofocus issue but at least it gives you some kind of cue so that you don't have sit there for 2 or 3 seconds wondering why your window hasn't opened yet.

In a non-root terminal, enter:

```
gedit admin:///usr/bin/gedit-notify
```

In **gedit-notify**, paste the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# purpose of this script: gedit under gnome Wayland has pretty messed up focusing and activation problems. First document/tab opened will focus normally but all the following ones open in the background without the traditional notification: "Your window is now read, click to focus". Its very distracting behavior because for the first 2 seconds you're wondering if your click was registered or not, if the app opened or not, etc. This script sends a notification every time you open a text file in the background. 

skip_list=true # you get notified but your notification list doesn't get spammed.

    gedit_inst=$(ps ax|grep " gedit "|wc -l)      #total number gedit windows + 1
    gedit_inst=$(expr $gedit_inst - 1)          #remove one from the count to account for the grep " gedit " process
    gedit_s=$(ps ax|grep " gedit -s"|wc -l)         # -s switch represents signle / independent instance for gedit. 
                                                # gedit_s represents the number of gedit windows running as 
                                                # independent instances + 1
    gedit_s=$(expr $gedit_s - 1)                # same logic as before
    gedit_inst=$(expr $gedit_inst - $gedit_s)   #substracts the # of windows running in independent instances 
                                #from total cound - because they don't affect the focus behavior. 
    if [ "$skip_list" = true ]; then
        n_arg0="--hint";n_arg1="int:transient:1"
    else
        n_arg0="-u";n_arg1="low"
    fi

    if [ "$gedit_inst" = 0 ]; then notify=false;fi 

n=0
while true; do
    n=$(expr $n + 1)
    file=$(eval echo \$$n)
    if ! [ -z "$file" ]; then 
        gedit "$file" &
        if [ -z "$err" -o "$err" = 0 ]; then 
                err="$?"
        fi
    else
        count=$(expr $n - 1) 
        if [ $count = 0 ]; then 
            if [ "$notify" != false ]; then notify-send $n_arg0 $n_arg1 "TEXT EDITOR is ready. Activate it manually.";fi
            gedit
        fi
        break; 
    fi          
done

if [ "$err" = 0 -a "$notify" != false ]; then 
    if [ $count -gt 1 ]; then
        notify-send $n_arg0 $n_arg1 "TEXT EDITOR is ready. Activate it manually." "$count files were opened."
    elif [ $count = 1 ]; then
        notify-send $n_arg0 $n_arg1 "TEXT EDITOR is ready. Activate it manually." "file: \"$1\""
    fi
elif [ "$err" != 0 ]; then
    notify-send -i error "TEXT EDITOR: I ran into some error(s) while opening your file(s)."
fi
```

save **gedit-notify**, and enter:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo chmod +x gedit-notify; sudo touch gedit-notify
gedit admin:///usr/share/applications/gedit-notify.desktop
```

in **gedit-notify.desktop**, paste the following code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Text Editor (Notify)
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=gedit-notify %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=gedit
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TextEditor;
X-GNOME-DocPath=gedit/gedit.xml
X-GNOME-FullName=Text Editor
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gedit
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.22.1
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-ExtraInfoScript=/usr/share/gedit/gedit-bugreport.sh
Actions=new-window;new-document;
Keywords=Text;Editor;Plaintext;Write;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gedit

X-AppStream-Ignore=true

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=gedit --new-window

[Desktop Action new-document]
Name=New Document
Exec=gedit --new-document
```

This will create a desktop shortcut that will show up as Text Editor (notify) in your dashboard and Open With menu. In nautilus, browse around, find a text file, right-click on it, select Properties, click on the Open With tab, select "Text Editor (Notify)", set as default. There will be 4 or 5 different types of text files that needs to have this process repeated. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: It is very unfortunate that you have to use this workaround. I have the same problem (I want gedit and nautilus --executed from terminal--) to steal focus (or at least come to the front). I found the same problem in Fedora (I also have Wayland). https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/112121/steal-focus-not-working/